# InnerWidth $(window).width() do not match actual width when in mobile debugging

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I am using Chrome to develop a mobile website.  In this website I do a lot based on the width of the screen.  I am running into an issue where when I try to retrieve the width through either

```
window.innerWidth
```

or

```
$(window).width()
```

it is slightly different than what I see the actual width is in the debugger

for example I removed all css and content ran this code

```
<html style-"width: 100vw"> <!-- 100% has the save effect -->
<head>
</head>
<body id="body" style-"width: 100vw">
</body>
</html>
```

the innerWidth property is 375 (emulating iphone6) but the actual width is 375.33

This may seem like a small difference but I have a side scrolling portion of the application and after a few scrolls (by device width) it is very apparent that the alignment is off by a few pixels and gets worse with each scroll.  I can only attribute this to the fact that I am scrolling by 375px at a time but I need to be scrolling at 375.33px  (when I manually account for the difference it works correctly)

To make matters worse, I tried the exact same code on a different machine and the measurements were correct.

I am scratching my head here and would appreciate any help

Answer (score 2):

`window.innerWidth` is used to find the

> Width (in pixels) of the browser window viewport including, if rendered, the vertical scrollbar.

([Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/innerWidth))

---

`$(window).width()` is a method that

> // Returns width of browser viewport

([Source](http://api.jquery.com/width/#width1))

---

The latter does not include the width of the scroll bar as part of the viewport's width (I used this page in chrome's dev tools and got `window.innerWidth = 1920` and `$(window).width() = 1899`, the difference being `21px` for the scroll bar). My guess is that your scroll bar on the mobile site has an extra `0.33px` for some reason. I would check the ways you're displaying/styling it, as that may increase the width and cause the difference of `0.33px`. Hopefully that helps a bit, if you can post any code that would also be more helpful to debug.

Comment: I was going to add a fiddle, but considering my code is trying to use VW's and the issue only occurs when emulating an iphone6 screen size it would directly apply.  Also, I have tested the code in multiple computers, but so far it has only happened to on 1